# how to delete python code that's not covered

Tags: python, dependencies, code-coverage, minify

Is there a tool that removes python code that isn't covered at run time, or a tool that removes code that isn't depended on by a particular function? If not, what would be a good approach?

Here is my problem more specifically:

I need the **maxflow subset** of the **networkx** algorithms module on github.

Usually I would just download the entire library and then import the modules I need however:

1). I need to physically print out some of these algorithms onto paper.

2). Some competitions have an online judge that runs your code. The judge doesn't have networkx installed, so I need to cut and paste code I need into a single .py file before uploading to the judge. The judge imposes a 50,000 byte file size limit.

For example, after cut and pasting one function

```
def ford_fulkerson(G, s, t, capacity='capacity'):
```

But ford_fulkerson has dependencies on other algorithms, networkx custom errors and the entire networkx graph and digraph classes.

After cut and pasting these dependencies, I went from 50 lines of code to 3000 lines of code.

I looked at the coverage on some test cases that should cover everything and the coverage is only at 39%. Most of that 39% is just reading function names of functions that aren't even used.

```
C:\Users\robert\code\play\spoj>coverage run TOSCORE.py < in.txt
No goal
Goal

C:\Users\robert\code\play\spoj>coverage report -m
Name      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------
TOSCORE     733    444    39%   226, 233, 236, 252, 280-283, 301, 377-389, 437-4
56, 489-497, 526-534, 568-570, 597, 618, 633, 655-658, 712-715, 772-801, 835, 86
4-869, 900-906, 948-949, 988-991, 1011-1014, 1107, 1115-1119, 1167-1170, 1195, 1
221, 1257-1260, 1297-1308, 1328-1331, 1357, 1361, 1406-1415, 1452, 1493-1512, 15
38, 1570-1574, 1600, 1636-1640, 1673-1677, 1704-1707, 1731-1733, 1757-1759, 1803
-1828, 2029, 2078-2091, 2142-2154, 2160, 2193-2203, 2232-2243, 2296, 2300-2301,
2305-2307, 2309-2311, 2359-2391, 2424-2425, 2455-2459, 2467, 2474, 2483-2484, 24
90-2491, 2498, 2502, 2551-2562, 2588-2599, 2608, 2645-2658, 2698-2709, 2747-2758
, 2798-2801, 2838-2841, 2859-2862, 2867, 2910, 2949-2963, 2979-2990, 3032-3055,
3084, 3091-3092, 3134-3140, 3148-3151, 3178-3180, 3192, 3198, 3208, 3254, 3265-3
283
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little script that removes comments and that was enough. It would have been better if I used the tokenizer but here it is anyway:

```
data = open("mini_nx.py").read().replace("nx.", "").splitlines()
data = [line for line in data if not line.strip().startswith("#")]

final_data = []
inside = False
for line in data:
    if not inside and line.strip().startswith('"""'):
        if line.strip().endswith('"""') and line.count('"""') > 1:
            final_data.append(line)
        else:
            line = line.rstrip('"')
            if '"' in line:
                line += '-"""'
            else:
                line += '"""-"""'
            final_data.append(line)
            inside = True
        continue
    if inside and line.endswith('"""'):
        inside = False
    elif not inside and line.strip():
        final_data.append(line)

with open("converted_mini_nx.py", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(final_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that one could, as a first attempt, use the output from `coverage` as input to a (say) Python script that read the original `TOSCORE.py` and wrote out a version of `TOSCORE.py` that omitted all the uncovered lines.

In practice, that approach might be a bit naive, though. A more sophisticated approach might be:

1. Take the list of uncovered lines produced by `coverage`.
2. Find the first block of uncovered lines longer than 1 line (given that single uncovered lines are not likely to be whole unused functions).
3. Write out a version of `TOSCORE.py` that omitted that block.
4. Run the test suite on the amended version of `TOSCORE.py`.
5. If the tests run successfully, go back to step 1, using the amended version of `TOSCORE.py` as the base version of `TOSCORE.py` on which the coverage is to be measured.
6. If omitting a given uncovered code block causes the test to fail, go on and try omitting the next uncovered code block.

This might take a while to execute but it should ensure that the resulting shortened code passes all the tests.

An intermediate approach that would take less time to execute would try to omit several uncovered code blocks at a time before running the tests again.

A more sophisticated approach might be to insert a `pass` statement in place of lines that we omit (prefixed with the indentation of the first omitted line) to deal with cases where the uncovered lines are contained in unused branches of `if` statements or unused `while` loops and therefore just omitting the lines would cause an error.

Comment: thanks. For example though, the Graph class has many methods. almost none of these methods are called but coverage says the method name has been covered because python needs to know what methods the class has even if those methods aren't used.
I may try something similar to what you mention as a quick and dirty solution if there aren't any pre-existing tools.